# Make a USB flash drive readable but not copyable

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I want to protect my USB flash drive in general so these files and directories are readable but *not* copyable so no one can make a copy of these files in my USB flash drive.

Is that possible?

Comment: If you can read it you can copy it, period.

Comment: if a program can read it, it can always store the bytes to another file. there's no way to prevent that

Answer (score -2):

You can control write-access separately from read-access on the files. But once you allow readability, the user is able to copy as well. Copy is implied in read-access.